# Converting dem and geotiff to collada model with texture?

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, collada

I have a digital elevation model (dem) file with corresponding orthophoto in geotiff format.

What I need to do is to create a 3D model of the terrain with textures (preferably in collada file)?

I would like an opensource or freeware solution, but I will consider commercial software if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is 3D plugin for Qgis:
http://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.org/en/docs-release/index.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: This plugin is excellent. I switched to FileExport.html template file and it created collada and obj files. Thank you!

Comment: @ZoranPetrović could you perhaps share how you managed to export the collada file? I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: @Flobin Select "FileExport.html" template and you can select file type when you open exported html file: https://qgis2threejs.readthedocs.io/en/docs-release/ExportSettings.html#template

Comment: @ZoranPetrović ah perhaps that functionality was discontinued or doesn’t exist on the mac, because I don’t see that option: https://imgur.com/a/LXMyAwe