# Open source solution to convert terrain data to collada?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis, software-recommendations, terrain, collada

I am exploring how to convert terrain information (DTED, SRTM, etc) to a 3D mesh file.  Collada is preferrable as it is very compatible.

I have read this: [Converting dem and geotiff to collada model with texture?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182371/convert-dem-and-geotiff-to-collada-model-with-texture)

and followed the process of exporting terrain in QGIS using Qgis2threejs, selecting the File Export template, but no .dae file object is created - only several .js files.

I get that broad questions are frowned upon on SE, but I'm not sure how else to phrase it.  Does anyone have a recommended method to convert a terrain raster to .dae or other widely compatible 3D file format?

Answer (score 1):

You can examine the answers to the  Bjørn Sandvik question  [to find the best open source tool  to create a Triangulated Irregular Network (TIN) from a Digital Elevation Model (DEM).](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2016/09/creating-tin-from-raster-dem.html)

1) With SAGA GIS [Creating TINs in SAGA GIS](http://blog.mastermaps.com/2016/09/creating-tins-in-saga-gis.html),  that can be used  in QGIS processing (Stereo Lithography File format, [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format))).

2) With Python and osgeo.gdal  [GIS SE: Generating a Mesh from DTM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/121873/2581) (Polygon File Format or Stanford Triangle Format, [PLY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLY_(file_format))) or with the [phstl module: Convert GDAL rasters to STL mesh](https://github.com/anoved/phstl) (STL format)

3) With GRASS GIS [v.out.ply](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/addons/v.out.ply.html) (PLY format)

4) With GDAL and [Meshlab](http://www.meshlab.net/) ([Automate your Meshlab workflow with MLX filter scripts](http://www.andrewhazelden.com/blog/2012/04/automate-your-meshlab-workflow-with-mlx-filter-scripts/)  (PLY format)

Comment: Appreciate the pointers. I'll research these over the next couple of days and if one of them works out, I'll mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these are really thorough enough to count as an answer.  My results are extremely distorted using PLY, whether I use GRASS, homegrown GDAL script, or even the Qgis2threejs plugin that allows an export of a .dae.  However, I do appreciate the pointers.